# Auto increment does not change

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change the auto increment value to make it starts from a specific number:

```
ALTER TABLE batchinfo AUTO_INCREMENT = 20000;
```

But when I query the records, the old numbering (1,2...) still exists, although, the statement seems successful. I'm using MySQL workbench. What could be the problem ?

Comment: It only affects the new record you INSERT. It doesn't affect your existing values.

Answer (score 5):

Altering `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not change past generated values, it only sets what the *next* generated value will be.  If you want to change past values then you will need to perform an `UPDATE`.  For example, something like this:

```
UPDATE batchinfo SET id = id + 19999;
```

**Be careful** that you don't have any other tables referencing this column, or their references will be invalidated.  (Unless those references are properly noted; only InnoDB tables support foreign keys.  And all of those foreign keys will have to be defined with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for this command to have the intended effect.)

Comment: +1 Because it's clear why AI won't change all past values, how to change all past values and the careful mention. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

That query doing the change of **next** `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. It doesn't change existing values.

If you already have values 1, 2, 3, ... 100, and then change `AUTO_INCREMENT` to 20000, next entered value will not be 101, but 20000.

Answer (score 1):

Your query sets a new start value for the auto-increment values generated from now on. It will not update the auto-increment values already stored in the table.